# How to find the corresponding data in my dataframe?

Tags: r, coordinates

I have a dataframe with about 500 coordinates, that I have plotted with ggplot into a worldmap. The location of some of my points doesnt make sense. Is there a quick way to find which points correspond to which data in my dataframe?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two methods come to mind. One is using filter interactively, to narrow in on the unusual points, and the other is using plotly, which will give you tool tips, and the ability to zoom in on points:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
#Using filter
dataframe |> filter((location_longitude > 100 &
                        location_longitude < 200) &
                       (location_latitude > 300 &
                          location_latitude < 400)
)
#Using plotly
(dataframe |> ggplot(aes(location_latitude, location_longitude)) + geom_point()) |> ggplotly()
```